# Convert mongoose createdBy timestamp into Unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am a bit new to MongoDB and Mongoose and I want to convert the created timestamp from Mongo into a Unix timestamp for easier comparison.

```
    async getComments(params) {
    //user who the comments was made for
    let _id = params;
    try {
        //get comments for current user
        let uFilter = { user: _id };
        let uFields = { comment: 1, createdBy: 1, created: 1 };
        const resultsData = await Comments.find(uFilter, uFields).populate({
            path: 'createdBy',
            select: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
        });

        console.log(resultsData);
        return { d: resultsData };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

What I get back is:

```
 {
_id: new ObjectId("0000000000000000000"),
comment: 'Comment made by user',
created: 2022-01-13T09:21:25.689Z,
createdBy: {
  _id: new ObjectId("61b750324596e539c7cadb9b"),
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
}
```

}

so the created field I want to convert into a Unix timestamp. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an aggregation pipeline. In there you can use `created: { $toInt: { $divide: [{ $toLong: "$created" }, 1000] } }`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the update. Is there a way that I can do the conversion on the front-end? I have a few functions I have to run in my query which I'm not sure how to handle just yet with aggregation. For example, my pagination function doesn't work with aggregation.

Comment: Of course, it is up to you where you convert the date. Libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in the frontend:-

```js
const { DateTime } = require('luxon')

module.exports.getMongoTimestamp = timestamp => {
    const timeStampArgs = timestamp.toString().split(' ')
    const timestampUnix = DateTime.fromRFC2822(`${timeStampArgs[0]}, ${timeStampArgs[2]} ${timeStampArgs[1]} ${timeStampArgs[3]} ${timeStampArgs[4]} ${timeStampArgs[5].replace('GMT', '')}`).toMillis()
    return parseInt(timestampUnix, 10)
}
```

I am using luxon to do it!